# Why, when I am transferring elements from 1d array to 2d array, on getting the last 1d array made from previous loop

Tags: java, arrays, file, token

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.charAt(0) != '#') {
                c++;
                //looking to get dimensions of line segments from file.  
                dimensions = new int[c][4];

                //Split my file input into an array of tokens(strings)
                tokens = line.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                    //Parse strings to int. 
                    dimtoke[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);

                    for (int k = 0; k < dimensions.length; k++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
                            //attempt to fill 2d array with contents from file.
                            dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I get a 2d array full of the last dimension in the file instead of all the dimensions. The dimensions come in groups of 4 in a single line of text, so i made a single array with those tokens from each line i read in from the file so i could parse them to ints.  something is happening in the process of transferring the 1d array of ints to the 2d array.

Comment: Why do you have four nested loops? Also, you've assigned values to `dimtoke[i]` (not `dimtoke[j]`), like `dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[i];`

Comment: Give an example of your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close {} the tokens loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                //Parse strings to int. 
                dimtoke[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}//you need a closing here
                for (int k = 0; k < dimensions.length; k++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
                        //attempt to fill 2d array with contents from file.
                        dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[j];
                    }
                }
```

I'll try to explain it to you.

Everytime you get an int in tokens with the instruction
    dimtoke[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);

Before getting the next int in dimtoke[i+1] you get into a loop where you fill all the ints in the 2d array with that dimitoke[i].

When those loops have finished(all the 2d array has been filled with only 1 int), you go again up and fill the dimitoke with the next int, and again, fill all the 2d array with that int.

What you need to do is to first finish the for loop and fill the dimitoke with the whole set of ints, and then, fill the 2D array with the ints in dimitoke.

Your problem was that you filled the whole array everytime you put an int in dimitoke, so everytime the whole 2d array was overwritten with only 1 int.

Another thing I expect to be wrong:

When you are filling the 2D array, you put the j variable in both dimensions and dimitoke, so if dimitoke lenght is not equal than the second array lenght of dimensions, you'll fill again every row with the same if dimitoke is greater, and indexOutOfBounds Excepcion if it's lesser. Here's an example:

dimitoke dimension = 10 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

if dimensions have dimension 4, the output of dimensions will be:

0,1,2,3

0,1,2,3

0,1,2,3

.
.. c rows.

To repair that, what you can do is to change the dimitoke variable for a int n (for example) and change the code like this:

```
int n =0;
for (int k = 0; k < dimensions.length; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[0].length; j++) {
                          //attempt to fill 2d array with contents from        file.
                         dimensions[k][j] = dimtoke[n];
                           n++;
                      }
                   }
```

I hope the error is out now

Answer (score 0):

Not completely know what you want to do. But I think you should separate the two loop:

1. assign value to the dimtoke.
2. assign value to dimensions.

So I think apparently, you should enclose the loop here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    //Parse strings to int. 
    dimtoke[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```